# Why this code is not working?? I need random number from 1-9

Tags: java, math

Why this code is not working? I need random number from 1-9

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class Mathrandom {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  int max = 9;
  int min = 1;
  int range = max - min + 1;

  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
   int rand = (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;

  }

  System.out.println(rand);
 }

}
```

Comment: "It isn't working" is not a meaningful problem statement. Please [edit] your question to include the details of *how* your program isn't working.  A brief glance at your code makes me think it won't compile since you're using `rand` out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the scope of `rand` is inside the `for` loop but you are trying to access it outside the `for` loop and therefore, your code won't be compiled successfully.

Do it as follows:

```
public class Mathrandom {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max = 9;
        int min = 1;
        int range = max - min + 1;

        int rand;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            rand = (int) (Math.random() * range) + min;
            System.out.println(rand);
        }
    }
}
```